# Reduce the headache on database when using ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

please I need your help how to reduce the database call when using `ModelChoiceField` as it requires a `queryset` and I have to use it three times separately with a model that is recursively foreign key on itself, the code is below:

ModelForm code in the init function

```
self.fields['category'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=queryset)
self.fields['super_category'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=)
self.fields['product_type'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=)
```

the model class:

```
class Category(ProjectBaseModel, AuditLogMixin):
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=_('Parent'))
```

what i tried to do is collect all ids of the desired categories in array and make only one filter queryset with them like the following:

```
category = auction.category
super_category = category.parent_id
product_type = super_category.parent_id
ids= [category.id,super_category.id,product_type.id]
queryset = Category.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

How to proceed with that solution

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly what you aim to do. Three queries is not that much. It also is rather strange to use `sub_category = category.parent_id`, since this refers to the parent, so the "super-category".

Comment: I edited the name of the fields

Comment: i will filter with the new id in each query in the whole table , can'ti optimize it in only one call for the DB

Comment: what is the *new id*? A database normally has indexes on *foreign key*s, and a part of these indexes is cached. So normally a second query filtering will not be that expensive.

Comment: so from your point of view to call the DB 3 separate queries times is the best performance

Comment: not per se the best. But Python/Django/... is not about the best performance. Python was designed with the idea that *development time is more costly than processing time*. A developer should more worry about big-oh performance, etc. and the rest can often be solved by buying more expensive machines, etc. Often these machines are cheaper than programmers paycheck.